# Responsive table not responding

Tags: css, html

I am currently trying to create a table that is responsive for mobile device unfortunately it is not going so well.

What I am trying to do is the following image:
[image]

So I am able to get an image to align with the Event and the hr tag and the same for the summer night to align. However, for more events part, I am not able to align the events correctly and so I thought a table would be best but it is not working out well.

I would like to know how I would approach to fix the following html and the css that I am using:

```css
/*----- general styles -----*/
html, body { font-family: "OpenSans", sans-serif;background-color:#f9f9f9 }

media (min-width: 1170px){
 body { width: 1170px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
 }
}
body { position: relative; }
h1, h2, h3 { font-family: "UrgeText", sans-serif; }
large, .large { font-size: 120%; }
.text-black { color: #000000; }
.text-gray { color: #888888; }
.bg-white { background-color: #FFFFFF;}
.bg-white1{background-color: #FFFFFF; height:auto;}/*07/15/2016*/
.bg-white2{background-color: #FFFFFF; height:214px;}/*07/15/2016*/
.hr{margin-top:-1px !important;}
.eventTop{margin-top:-14px;}
.margin-right { margin-right: 30px; }
.no-padding-right {  padding-right:0; }
.no-padding-left { padding-left:0; }
.no-margin { margin: 0; }
.no-margin-right { margin-right: 0; }
.moreEventMargin{margin-top:-2px; margin-left:20px;}/*81px top*/
.buttonHome{margin-top:-12px; margin-left:380px; } /*-80px top*/
.btn-standard {  
 border-color: #000;
 border-radius: 0;
 background-image: none;
}

/*07/15/2016*/
.image-padding{
 margin-top:34px;
 border:10px solid #f9f9f9;
}

/*07/15/2016*/
.featured{
 color:#337ab7;
}

/*For Doctor Finder shift address Address2 @ROB*/
.shiftAdd{margin-left:62px;}

.shiftAddUrgent{margin-left:80px;}

/*@ROB*/
.padding{
 padding-bottom:2px
}
/*@ROB* 06/15/2016*/
.ignore{

}


/*******************************************************/
/*07/07/2016 comment out padding-bottom*/
.navbarpadding {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.navbarapp-padding{
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.body-padding{
 margin-top:70px;/*Note: This is for Mura. For production, we would need to see the actual results.*/
}

.finder-padding{
  margin-top:50px;/*Note: This is for Mura. For production, we would need to see the actual results.*/
}

/*07/07/2016 called container fluid to add the margin between navbar and body content*/


/*Full size of the calendar with no scroll bar 07/05/2016*/
/*.fullheight{
 margin-bottom:500px;
}
/*07/06/2016 To remove the particular height from calendar*/
/*.fc-scroller{
 height:auto !important;
}*/

/*07/11/2016 to increase the width of the background*/
/*.bg-white1{
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
 width:34.8%;
}*/

/*event mobile devices*/
@media(max-width:800px){
 .centerEvent{text-align:center;}
 .moreEventMargin{margin-top:16px; margin-left:29px;}/*0px top and left 57px*/
 .buttonHome{margin-top:-21px; margin-left:0px;} 
 .bg-white2{background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 0px;}
}

/*allows the scroller to appear on mobile version 07/11/2016*/
@media(max-width:480px){
 .fc-scroller{
  overflow-x:hidden !important;
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
  height:100px !important
 }
 /*07/15/2016*/
 .bg-white1{background-color: #FFFFFF; height:auto;}/*07/15/2016*/
 .centerEvent{text-align:center;}
 .moreEventMargin{margin-top:20px; margin-left:16px;}
 .buttonHome{margin-top:0px; margin-left:2px;}
}

.override-col-xs-2, .override-col-xs-10{
 float:right;
 min-height:1px;
}

/*Expand Events on home page 07/11/2016*/
@media (min-width:992px){
 .override-md-offset-3{
  width:3.5%; /*3%*/
 }
 .override-col-md-2{
  float:left;
  width:83.66666667%;
 }
 .paddingMore{margin-top:-90px; padding-left:220px;}
}

/*Change button color for slideshows override theme.min.css 07/05/2016*/
.btn-info1 {
  color: white;
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  border-color: #46b8da;
  background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #004377 0, #004377 100%);
  background-image:-linear-gradient(to bottom, #004377 0, #004377 100%);
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  border-color:#00437;
}

.slideText{
 color:white;
}

/*Following is to center the 2016 copyright Regal ... footer*/
@media (min-width:1200px){
 .override-col-lg-6{
  width:63%;
  margin-left:252px;
 }
}

/*****************************************************/
/*override Theme.min.css file @ROB*/
.navbar .navbar-nav:not(.ignore){
 padding-bottom:10px;
 margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.container-fluid.ng-scope:not(#home-content){
 padding-top:20px;
}

.break-all { word-break: break-all }

/*Added by Rob 05/13/2016*/
.calendarResize{width:100%;}

/*Added by Rob 05/31/2016*/
.fixIconCal{padding-left:0px;}

.fc-left h2{
 font-size:22px;
}

/*If we are going to use a style sheet Added by @Rob*/
@media print {
  .visible-print  { display: inherit !important; }
  .hidden-print   { display: none !important; }
}

@media (min-width: 450px){
 .has-margin-top { margin-top:20px; }
 .no-margin-top { margin-top:0; }
}

/*------ navbar.cfm, navbar_ap.cfm */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
 header { height: 120px; }
}

.absolute-position {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; 
 left: 0;
 right: 0; 
 margin: 0 auto; 
}

@media (max-width: 480px){
 .fc-view-container{width:109%;}
 
/*07/08/2016 Added the following so title is visible*/ 
 .visible-xs{
  display:block !important;
  margin-top:40px;
 }
 
/*07/08/2016 Added the following so adjust indicators*/
 .carousel-indicators{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 15;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: -30%;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
     text-align: center;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 639px){
 .company-logo { width: 210px; }
}

@media (min-width: 640px){
 .company-logo { width: 300px; }
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
 .company-logo { width: 400px; }
}

/*Added by Rob 05/13/2016*/
@media (max-width: 800px){
 .fc-view-container{width:94%;}
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar  { background: rgba(0,119,192,1); }

.navKeywords { border-right-style: none; }

.navKeywordsSubmit { 
 border-left-style: none;
 border-color: #000;
 }

.navbar { 
 border: 0; 
 box-shadow: none; 
}

.well { 
 background-color: initial; 
 background-image: none; 
 border: none; 
 box-shadow: none; 
 padding-left: 0; 
 padding-right: 0; 
}

.well .nav-list .nav-list a{ 
 font-size: 90%;
} 
/*Added 06/15/2016 */
@media (max-width: 1023px){
 .navbar-opacity {
  /*background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);*/
  background-color:#f9f9f9;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255);
  /*background:#f9f9f9;*/
  filter: initial;
  /* For IE 8*/
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#00000000)";
 }
 .navbar-opacity-home {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  /*background-color:#f9f9f9;*
  background:#f9f9f9;
  filter: initial;
  /*For IE 8*/
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#00000000)";
 }
 /*Added by Rob. Fixed the issue with footer being cut off in tablet and mobile sites*/
 .col-lg-2{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
 }
}

@media (min-width:1024px){
 .navbar-opacity { 
  /*background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);*/
  background-color:#f9f9f9;
  /*background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);*/
  background: rgba(249, 249, 249, .7);
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#00000000);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#00000000)";
 }
 .navbar-opacity-home { 
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color:#f9f9f9;
  /*background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);*/
  background: rgba(249, 249, 249, .7);
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#00000000);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00000000, endColorstr=#00000000)";
 }
}



@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .navbar { background-image: none; }
 
}

@media (min-width: 768) and (max-width: 1024){
 .navbar-header .container {
  width: auto;
 }
}

/*display image in mobile devices for News/Events page @ROB*/
@media (max-width: 767px){
 .upcoming-events-image { 
  max-width: 180px;
  max-height: 180px;
  width:95%;
 }
 
 .hidden-xs.col-md-2{
  display:inline !important;
 }
 .fc-scroller{
  overflow: visible !important;
  display:inline-block !important;
  }
 .fc-scroller.fc-day-grid-container{
  height:auto !important;
 }
}

/*Fixes the icon calendar @ROB*/
@media(min-width: 968px){
 .icon-fix{
  margin-left:-15px;
 }
}

.navbar-nav > li > a { padding: 10px; }

@media (min-width: 1024px){
 #navPrimary li a:link
 , #navPrimary li a:visited { color: black; }
 
 #navPrimary li.active a:link
 , #navPrimary li.active a:visited { color: #0077C0; }
 
 #navPrimary li a:hover
 , #navPrimary li a:active{ color: #0077C0; }
 
 #navPrimary li.first a{ padding-left:0; }
 
 #navPrimary li.last a{ padding-right:0; }
 
 .nav>li>a:hover{ 
  text-decoration:underline;
  background-color:transparent 
 }
 
 .nav-tabs>li>a:hover{ border-color:initial }
 
 #navStandard ul.nav li a:link
 , nav#navStandard ul.nav li a:visited { color: #808080; }
 
 #navStandard ul.nav li a:hover
 , nav#navStandard ul.nav li a.active { color: #0077C0; }
 
 #navStandard ul.nav li a.active { font-weight: bold; }
 
 .navbar .navbar-nav>.active>a {  
  background-color:transparent; 
  color: #0077C0;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 1023px){
 a.navbar-brand { padding-right: 0; }
}

.bw-button { 
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 }

.radio-custom { display: none; }

.radio-label-custom {
 border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
 margin: auto 1px;
 color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
 background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 padding-left: 3px;
 padding-right: 3px;
 padding-top: 2px;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
 line-height: 95%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
}
.radio-custom:checked + .radio-label-custom {
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

/*------ end navbar.cfm, navbar_ap.cfm */

/*----- home.cfm -----*/



#homepage .carousel { margin-top:auto; }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
 #homepage .carousel .item{ height:650px; }
 
 #homepage .carousel .carousel-caption { 
  left: 20px;
  top: 90px;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 767px){
/*07/08/2016 Modified #homepage .carousel .item { height: 200px; } and added margin-top:85px*/
 #homepage .carousel .item { 
  height: 200px; 
  margin-top:85px;
 }
 #homepage .carousel .item img { 
  max-width: 100%; 
  height: auto; 
  display: block; 
 }
 
 #homepage .carousel .carousel-caption { 
  left: 0;
  top: 35px;
  color: #0077C0;
 }
}

#homepage .carousel .carousel-caption { 
 background-color: transparent;
 text-align: left;
 }


@media (min-width: 1024px){
 #homepage .carousel .carousel-caption { 
  left: 10; 
  top: 160px;
  width: 500px;
 }

 .carousel-caption h1
 , .carousel-caption h2 *{ color: #0077C0 }
 
 #homepage .carousel .item img{
  <!-- [if IE 9]>
   top:200px;

   width: 100%;
  <![endif]-->
 }
 
 .slideHeader {
  font-size: 40px; 
  color: #0077C0; 
  font-family: "UrgeText"; 
 }
}

@media (min-width: 1170px){
 #homepage .carousel .carousel-caption { 
  left: 130px;
 }
}

/****************Carousel Expands. Carousel-caption and body content remains the same ROB*********************/
@media (min-width:1281px){
    #homepage .carousel .carousel-caption { 
        left:auto;
        right:auto;
        max-width:1263px;
        margin-left:70px;
    }
    .footer-links{
        margin:auto;
        max-width:1263px;
    }
    .bodyPages{
        margin:auto !important;
        max-width:1263px !important;
    }
    #searchForm{
        margin:auto !important;
        max-width:1263px !important;
    }
  /* body{
        /*max-width:1263px !important;
        margin:auto;
    }*/
 .depth-2 {
  margin: auto;
  max-width:1263px !important;
 }
 .depth-1{
  margin: auto;
  max-width:1263px !important;
 }
 /*.carousel-caption {
  max-width: 775.81px;
  margin: auto;
    }
 .row.item img{
  width:100%;
 }*/
}
/*********************************************************/

@media (min-width:1263px){
 body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
 }
}

#home-content { padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0 } 

.quickLink {
 /*border: 1pt solid black;*/
 padding-bottom: 10pt;
}



.upcoming-events-image { 
 max-width: 180px;
 max-height: 180px;
 }

 .expand-featured-event{
  width:74%;
 }

#featured-event, #more-events { 
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 padding: 15px 0px;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px){
 #featured-event, #more-events{
  height: 214px;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 
 #featured-event .featured-event-title {
  width: 170px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
 
 #featured-event .featured-event-summary {
  width: 170px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
}

/*----- end home.cfm -----*/


/*----- inc/footer.cfm ----*/

footer table{
 margin: 30px auto;
 border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 20px 20px;
}

footer td {
 vertical-align: top;
}

.footer-links {
 margin-top: 20px;
 font-size: 12px;
}
/*Modified by Rob*/
/*.row {
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}*/
@media (max-width: 1023px){
 #footer-affiliation { 
  background-color: #0077C0; 
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
  padding: 5px;
 }
 
 #footer-affiliation a { color: rgb(255, 255, 255) }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px){
 .footer-column { margin-right: 20px }
}
.fc-time{display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="centerEvent">
       <div class="hidden-xs override-col-md-offset-3 col-md-2  centerEvent" style="margin-left:30px">
        <p class="image-center upcoming-events-image image-padding"><img src="#local.item.getImageURL()#" alt="#HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getTitle())#"> </p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-md-offset-0 col-md-2 bg-white1 expand-featured-event" id="featured-event">
       <table width="94%">
        <tbody>
         <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
           <h4 class="featured"><strong>FEATURED EVENT</strong></h4>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>
           <hr class="hr" />
          </td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
        <div class="eventTop"> 
         <h6 class="ellipsis h6size"><!--- Title --->
          <div class="featured-event-title featured">
          <strong>#HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getValue('title'))#</strong>
          </div>
         </h6>           
          <small>
            <!--- date --->
            <!--- start date --->
            #LSDateFormat(local.item.getValue('displayStart'))#
             <!--- end date (if 'daily' event, and grouping is requested) --->
             <cfif YesNoFormat(arguments.groupDailyEvents)>
              <cfquery dbtype="query" name="subRS">
               select *
               from rs
               where rs.contentid = <cfqueryparam value="#local.item.getValue('contentid')#" />
              </cfquery>
              <cfif subRS.recordcount gt 1>
               <!--- end date --->
               <cfset enddate = ListLast(ValueList(subRS.displaystop)) />
               <cfif IsValid('date', enddate)>
                - #LSDateFormat(enddate)#
               </cfif>
              </cfif>
              <cfset local.listIDs = ListAppend(local.listIDs, local.item.getValue('contentid')) />
             </cfif>
          </small>
          <small>
            <!--- Summary --->
            <div class="featured-event-summary">
             <cfif Len(local.item.getValue('summary'))>
              #local.item.getValue('summary')#
             </cfif>
            </div>
           </small>
          <a href="##"><small>Learn more &gt;</small></a>
          <br />
        </div>
         <cfelse>
         <div class="paddingMore">
          <cfif ctr eq 2>
           <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-md-offset-0 override-col-md-2 moreEventMargin">
            <small><strong class="featured" style="margin-bottom:5px">MORE EVENTS</strong></small><br />
           </cfif>
            <div style="margin-top:5px">
             <small>#LSDateFormat(local.item.getValue('displayStart'))#</small><br />
             <small><strong>#HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getValue('title'))#</strong></small>
            </div>
            <br />
             </cfif>
            </cfif>
            <cfset ctr++ />
            </cfloop>
           </div>  
           <button class="btn btn-info btn-md resizable buttonHome centerEvent" type="button" onClick="parent.location='http://oc2-web03/regal_prod/index.cfm/news-events/events-calendar/'"><small>SEE ALL EVENTS &gt;</small></button><br />
         </div>
        </div>
     </div><!---closes the bg-white1 div--->
```

Comment: A table is probably not the right choice here as you're asking it at some point to re-order it's content from a multi-column to single column. You should also state what the desired layout is for various device sizes. Right now we're all guess what you want.

Comment: (1) This has nothing to do with ColdFusion, just with the final, rendered HTML and CSS. (2) You should probably look into using a responsive CSS framework like Bootstrap, Foundation or Skeleton.

Comment: I don't see where in your CSS you've attempted to make the table responsive.